# Is it ok to create a member manually in the database?

Tags: members, authentication

I am using a payment gateway that is not supported by any of the existing modules/plugins. They can provide a script that I an modify to write directly to the data.

I tested by:
Logging in via phpmyadmin and adding a new row to the member table. I entered username, screenname, password (selected sha1), group, language, time zone and hit go.

It created the member, and when I logged in first time a SALT value was added.

Unique_id remained blank, and crypt_key has a NULL value.

I have httpd authentication enabled in EE. I am able to log in to the templates successfully using the new login.

Will not having the unique and crypt key screw things up and this is a bad idea?

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

I've had to build a member importer for a client's website in which I did the same thing you're thinking about doing: inserting a member directly into the database.

As long as you add all of the fields that are required, you are good to go. Just look up the EE way of adding members and duplicate that.

Just don't forget about the `exp_member_data` and `exp_member_homepage` tables. I didn't include those at first, and members wouldn't work until I fixed that.

Comment: So it doesnt matter if the unique and crypt fields are empty?

Comment: It doesn't require the crypt, but I did include the unique_id... I just automatically generated a unique_id for the purposes of my importer... with `$unique_id = substr(md5($line[3]), 0, 40);` where line3 was the email address, I think. Didn't seem to conflict with anything.

Comment: As I mentioned, pay attention to what's required in the SQL structure. unique_id doesn't allow null.